# idempotent matrices and transformations

Tags: matrices, fourier-transform

What is the significance of idempotent matrices?  Are there any idempotent transformations in signal processing that are widely used?  Are there any practical applications of idempotent transformations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, matrix algebra theory has many applications, e.g., to to Statistics and Econometrics, Image and Signal processing and many other areas. There is a new branch of analysis, called "Idempotent Analysis". It looks like that this might be interesting for you, but I am not familiar with it. The introduction to the book ["Idempotent Analysis and Its Applications"](https://books.google.at/books?id=Ms3rCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=applications+of+idempotent+transformations+to+fourier&source=bl&ots=8s1ukQ80jV&sig=uCshTEpOqwxlZXzpkfVuUm8O-e4&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAmczco8XNAhUhBcAKHeSLCN8Q6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=applications%20of%20idempotent%20transformations%20to%20fourier&f=false) gives many applications.